# Find the p.d.f (variable transformation) - Are my things right?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

For Continuous random variables, $X$ whose P.D.F is $f(x) = \frac{2}{3} x$ on the interval $(1,2)$. I'm trying to find the P.D.F $g(y)$ for $Y = \frac{2}{X}$.

Method $1$)
C.D.F $G(Y) = P(Y \leq y) = P( \frac{2}{y} \leq X)$ $= \int_{\frac{2}{y}}^2 f(x) dx = \frac{4}{3}(1- {1 \over {y^2}}) $ , $1 <y<2$

Hence $g(y)$ = ${{d} \over {dy}} G(y) = {8 \over {3y^3} }$ , $1 <y <2$

Plus, I'm trying this by different way for efficiency for time. Here is my new method.

Method $2$ )
Since the $x = \frac{2}{y}$, substitute this into  $f(x) = \frac{2}{3} x$. Plus  I got a idea form the Jacobian for two variables.  In this case, $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{-2}{y^2}$

Hence $g(y) = \frac{4}{3y} \vert \frac{dx}{dy}   \vert  =  \frac{8}{3y^3}$ , $1 <y<2$

So my question is I want to know my answer is right or not.

Plus when it comes to the method 2, I can't sure those method does generally hold. Is that true method for the transforming "1 variable" to the other variable? Please verify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you mentioned is well known as Jacobian transformation, related to

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

They are equivalent. Given the transformation $h(x) = 2/x$ is monotonic on the support of $X$ (here is strictly decreasing), using the CDF method, we have

$$ g_Y(y) = \frac {\partial} {\partial y}\Pr\{Y \leq y\} 
= \frac {\partial} {\partial y}\Pr\{h(X) \leq y\}
= \frac {\partial} {\partial y}\Pr\{X > h^{-1}(y)\}$$

The inequality sign at last depends on whether $h$ is increasing or decreasing - the sign is flipped when it is decreasing.

And by chain rule,

$$ \frac {\partial} {\partial y}\Pr\{X > h^{-1}(y)\} = 
\frac {\partial} {\partial y}[1 - \Pr\{X \leq h^{-1}(y)\}]
= -f_X(h^{-1}(y))\frac {\partial h^{-1}(y)} {\partial y}$$

Note that since $h$ is decreasing, the derivative at last is negative as well, so the resulting pdf is still positive. Combining $h$ is increasing case, you can conclude that

$$g_Y(y) = f_X(h^{-1}(y))\left| \frac {\partial h^{-1}(y)} {\partial y} \right| $$